# JavaScriptHTML iFrame Variable Access

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a variable from the main HTML of the website to some JavaScript running inside of an iFrame.

Unfortunately I can't access the main HTML anymore. All I can edit is a iFrame inside of the HTML. My current plan is to run an iFrame inside of the iFrame to load the page again from inside of the iFrame. Can I then access the variable?

Here is a over visual representation:

```
HTML
Var amount = 5;
iFrame
  JavaScript
    Var variable;
  iFrame
    Website
  Variable = amount;
```

Comment: you wanna get a variable from the main page inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a variable in your parent page `var firstName = "Jack"`

Now in the iframe you can access it like this:

```
var nameFromParentWindow = parent.firstName;
```